# What are the aspect ratios for all Android phone and tablet devices?

Tags: android, mobile

I'm looking for a list of all screen aspect ratios for popular Android based Phones and Tablets.

Comment: [More complete answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23009368/199364)

Answer (score 184):

In case anyone wanted more of a visual reference:

[image: aspect_ratio_visual_reference]

Decimal approximations reference table:

```
╔══════════════════════════╦════════════════════════╦════════════════════════╗
║       aspect ratio       ║     decimal approx.    ║     decimal approx.    ║
║ [long edge x short edge] ║ [short edge/long edge] ║ [long edge/short edge] ║
╠══════════════════════════╬════════════════════════╬════════════════════════╣
║         19.5 x 9         ║        0.462...        ║        2.167...        ║
╠══════════════════════════╬════════════════════════╬════════════════════════╣
║          19 x 9          ║        0.474...        ║         2.11...        ║
╠══════════════════════════╬════════════════════════╬════════════════════════╣
║        ~18.7 x 9         ║        0.482...        ║        2.074...        ║
╠══════════════════════════╬════════════════════════╬════════════════════════╣    
║         18.5 x 9         ║        0.486...        ║        2.056...        ║
╠══════════════════════════╬════════════════════════╬════════════════════════╣
║          18 x 9          ║           0.5          ║            2           ║
╠══════════════════════════╬════════════════════════╬════════════════════════╣
║          19 x 10         ║        0.526...        ║           1.9          ║
╠══════════════════════════╬════════════════════════╬════════════════════════╣
║          16 x 9          ║         0.5625         ║        1.778...        ║
╠══════════════════════════╬════════════════════════╬════════════════════════╣
║           5 x 3          ║           0.6          ║        1.667...        ║
╠══════════════════════════╬════════════════════════╬════════════════════════╣
║          16 x 10         ║          0.625         ║           1.6          ║
╠══════════════════════════╬════════════════════════╬════════════════════════╣
║           3 x 2          ║        0.667...        ║           1.5          ║
╠══════════════════════════╬════════════════════════╬════════════════════════╣
║           4 x 3          ║          0.75          ║        1.333...        ║
╚══════════════════════════╩════════════════════════╩════════════════════════╝
```

*Changelog:*

- *May 2018:* Added `56x27 === ~18.7x9` (Huawei P20), `19x9` (Nokia X6 2018) and `19.5x9` (LG G7 ThinQ)
- *May 2017:* Added `19x10` (Essential Phone)
- *March 2017:* Added `18.5x9` (Samsung Galaxy S8) and `18x9` (LG G6)

Comment: 3:4 to make an image fit to most screen sizes in portrait mode.

Comment: 16:10 = 8:5, 18:9 = 2:1, 18.5:9 = 37:18

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of that. I decided to stick with the numbers that producers of the devices are using (e.g. look at the website promoting LG G6).

Comment: @BartekLipinski BTW what does the visual representation implies?

Comment: @GayanWeerakutti I gives you the ability to have visual comparison between different aspect ratios. So that e.g. you could see how much difference there is between the "widest" 4x3 and the "narrowest" 21x9 (which I have not yet put in the graphic). Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 161):

I researched the same thing several months ago looking at dozens of the most popular Android devices. I found that every Android device had one of the following aspect ratios (from most square to most rectangular):

- 4:3
- 3:2
- 8:5
- 5:3
- 16:9

And if you consider portrait devices separate from landscape devices you'll also find the inverse of those ratios (3:4, 2:3, 5:8, 3:5, and 9:16)

---

[More complete answer here: stackoverflow community spreadsheet of Android device resolutions and DPIs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23009368/199364)

Comment: I don't think there is a ratio of 5:4. Can you give an example? and there is the 15:9 ratio that includes many devices such as 1280x768

Comment: Also note: 16:10 == 8:5

Comment: The figures listed cover iPhones and Windows Phone as well.

Comment: Now that the Blackberry Passport is out and runs Android apps, you might want to add 1:1 for its perfectly square 1440x1440 display.  If you have smallScreens=false, I would guess that Passport would be ruled out, as anything with less than a 1.5 aspect ratio would require smallScreens=true.  But if smallScreens=true then you may find yourself in that unusual ratio, for which many apps will not have tested.  Amazon's app store is pre-installed on the Passport and Amazon will supposedly automatically make your app available on the Passport if its manifest does not rule it out.

Comment: Galaxy Tab 7.0 is 1024 x 600 or ~ 17:10 and iphone 6 plus is 1920 x 1080 or ~17.7:10 (obviously not android but interesting for those of us designing apps cross platform)

Comment: There is also 1.54 for Samsung note 10.1 - not sure how to represent it in x/y format

Comment: @Nativ Note 10.1 has 1280x800 or 2560x1600 (2014 edition). In both cases it's 16:10.

Comment: Note that if you take pictures, the aspect ratio of the resulting picture may differ considerably. For instance, most 5:3 phones produce 4:3 pictures.

Comment: So you mean if I make a popup with aspect ratio of 3:4 then it will show exactly 100% same on all Android devices without any text or button being cut off?

Comment: [Sony Xperia 1](https://www.gsmarena.com/sony_xperia_1-9543.php) has a ratio of 21:9.

Answer (score 5):

It is safe to assume that popular handsets are WVGA800 or bigger. Although, there are a good amount of HVGA screens, they are of secondary concern.

List of android screen sizes

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Aspect ratio calculator

http://andrew.hedges.name/experiments/aspect_ratio/

Answer (score 3):

the best way to calculate the equation is simplified. That is, find the maximum divisor between two numbers and divide:

ex.

```
1920:1080 maximum common divisor 120 = 16:9
1024:768  maximum common divisor 256 = 4:3
1280:768  maximum common divisor 256 = 5:3
```

may happen also some approaches

Answer (score 0):

The Sony Tablet P is old, but it can switch between 32:15 and 32:30 for each app in landscape mode, and vice-versa in portrait mode, so that's a minimum range to aim for