# List of Android aspect ratios?

Tags: android, aspect-ratio

I'm developing a game for mobile devices and have come to the point where I need to adapt it to different aspect ratios.

I've looked around for the common Android aspect ratios but most resources only list the DPI value.

Anyone know any resources I may have missed, or might happen to know the common aspect ratios off the top of their head?

Comment: Here yah go :)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7199492/what-are-the-aspect-ratios-for-all-android-phone-and-tablet-devices

Comment: Thanks, but I was hoping for a link to a more official resource =P. I'm worried that might be outdated too since it was from a year ago.

Comment: This is akin to asking what the most popular aspect ratios are of browser windows for a Web app, or the most popular aspect ratios of any desktop OS window. Apps that depend upon matching an aspect ratio are fundamentally flawed, IMHO. "I was hoping for a link to a more official resource" -- there is no "official resource", because device manufacturers are welcome to make any aspect ratio they want, so Google focuses on screen size and density.

Comment: I wasn't intending to build my game to match an aspect ratio. I just wanted to pick the squarest of the common ones to base my smallest field of view on. What you say makes sense though, so I guess I'll have to make do.

Answer (score 1):

Typically I'm not a fan of providing links as answers, but there is a community wiki here on SO that is maintaining a list of Android aspect ratios. It contains 30+ devices so far.

Found here: [Is there a list of screen resolutions for all Android based phones and tablets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7587854/is-there-a-list-of-screen-resolutions-for-all-android-based-phones-and-tablets)

Answer (score -1):

```
320dp: a typical phone screen (240x320 ldpi, 320x480 mdpi, 480x800 hdpi, etc). = 3:4
480dp: a tweener tablet like the Streak (480x800 mdpi). = 3:5
600dp: a 7” tablet (600x1024 mdpi ~= 640x1024). 10:16  
720dp: a 10” tablet (720x1280 mdpi, 800x1280 mdpi, etc). 9:16
```

from: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html
also: <s>http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Android_devices</s>

Comment: If this was the answer you were looking for please mark it as answered with the checkmark on the left

Comment: This is by no means a comprehensive list of existing *aspect ratios*. There are roughly a dozen.