# Is it necessary to develop for multiple screen-resolutions in Unity?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, mobile, screen-resolution

I am developing an android mobile game in Unity. I am developing it on a 1920x1080 screen-resolution. The problem is: Not every smartphone has a 1920x1080 resolution. There are higher and lower resolutions. Do I have to develop the game for every resolution, or is it enough to focus on the 1920x1080 screen-resolution? Developing and redesigning the game for every resolution would be much work.

I tried to put the gameobjects into Canvas, panels and vertical layouts to make them responsive. But this is only working for UI. GameObjects like the character, etc. are not responsive to the screen-resolution.

I couldn't find anything useful for this problem. Most tutorials are for UI responsiveness, but not for GameObjects. Is there an option, that Unity make the game fit in every resolution?

Comment: Asking for opinions/recommendations is explicitly off-topic on SO.

Comment: I can see how asking "Do I have to ___?" is more of a question of opinion. I think it can be reframed as "How to ___?" which seems more what the OP was after. I suggested an edit to that effect.
Knowing how to develop an app in a single resolution that still looks good on other resolutions is a useful trick to know and would benefit others looking for the same info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is no, you don't *have to* develop for multiple screen resolutions. If you don't want to, one solution is to develop for the "narrowest" resolution you're likely to encounter (probably 16:9, though there are narrower ones) and treat that space as your "playable area" (by not letting the character go outside that area, for example). If someone plays your game using a wider resolution, there will be extra space on the edges, so make sure you either fill that space with something (like background art for example) or "letterbox" it with black lines.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28240009/1861453) which includes an excellent visual reference of different screen ratios.

Comment: *`though there are narrower ones`* My search the other day revealed that 18:9 is becoming the new standard. And holy heck is looks awful. It is also not called 2:1 for some inane reason.